# Controlling location of SVG image on web page with CSS

Tags: css, svg

I am working with an SVG drawing. This has been created by another developer and delivered to me for use on a web site.

It uses the raphael.js vector graphics library to draw the map and animations.

It is inserted into the web page with two lines of javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="raphael.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="maine_map.js"></script>
```

My challenge is that I cannot get this svg file to appear where I need it to in the page. It needs to appear to the right of the slide show on this demo page:

http://owlpress.net/work/

Rather than appearing in the parent div I created for it, it appears floating at the bottom of the page. I've played with the CSS every which way, and I'm stumped. If anyone can help point me in the right direction, that would be wonderful.

Susan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In main_map.js you have:

```
// Insert the <div> into the body document.

    document.body.appendChild(div);
```

This is the reason why it is generated after everything.

Create your own div + id and appendChild() to it instead body tag.
**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/FcrEI)**

```
var apme = document.getElementById('ap');
// Create the div we'll be slotting the map into and set it to the correct size.
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.setAttribute('id', "mobilize_maine_map");
div.style.width = "200px";
div.style.height = "200px";
div.style.borderWidth = "1px";
div.style.borderColor = "#000";
div.style.borderStyle = "solid";

// Insert the <div> into the heml document.
apme.appendChild(div);
```

Now , this div is inserted inside the div#ap. this div can be anywhere you wish inside your markup.

---

```
<edit>
```

you did :

```
// Create the div we'll be slotting the map into and set it to the correct size.
var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.setAttribute('id', "mobilize_maine_map");
    div.style.width = divWidth+"px";
    div.style.height = divHeight+"px";
//  div.style.borderWidth = "0px";
//  div.style.borderColor = "#000";
//  div.style.borderStyle = "solid";

// Insert the <div> into the heml document.
document.body.appendChild(div);

var apme = document.getElementById('map');
// Create the div we'll be slotting the map into and set it to the correct size.
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.setAttribute('id', "mobilize_maine_map");
div.style.width = "203px";
div.style.height = "306px";
div.style.borderWidth = "0px";
div.style.borderColor = "#000";
div.style.borderStyle = "solid";

// Insert the <div> into the heml document.
apme.appendChild(div);
```

*This makes 2 div with same id and this is not what you look for :).*

**You should have removed  this :**

```
// Create the div we'll be slotting the map into and set it to the correct size.
var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.setAttribute('id', "mobilize_maine_map");
    div.style.width = divWidth+"px";
    div.style.height = divHeight+"px";
//  div.style.borderWidth = "0px";
//  div.style.borderColor = "#000";
//  div.style.borderStyle = "solid";

// Insert the <div> into the heml document.
document.body.appendChild(div);
```

**and replace it with :**

```
var apme = document.getElementById('map');
// Create the div we'll be slotting the map into and set it to the correct size.
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.setAttribute('id', "mobilize_maine_map");
    div.style.width = divWidth+"px";
    div.style.height = divHeight+"px";

// Insert the <div> into the heml document.
apme.appendChild(div);
```

Comment: This does the job. Thank you very much. I never would have figured this out on my own!

Comment: Now that I've got this working, I realize that the script is pushing additional blank space at the bottom of the page - where the SVG map was before you suggested the above edit. Do you have any ideas of how I might address that?

Comment: @user2984710 i'll edit my answer to show you. do not hesitate to give point or accept answer by the way

Answer (score 0):

I tried on the svg itself position: relative, left:1050, and bottom:909; and I at least got in the right general area.